# Volley and Https

Tags: android, ssl, https, android-volley

I am designing my first app that will send data to a server. I am using volley for the Post and Get commands . Now i am starting into securing my code and found that connecting via SSL is most recommended .

1- Is it enough to put the url with "https" and Volley will handle the certificate creation ? or I should use the solution found in this answer with the HttpsTrustManager extra class : [Making a HTTPS request using Android Volley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045795/making-a-https-request-using-android-volley)

2- I also found recommendations for using a "keyStore" which i dont know how to use it in volley  ?? thx in advance

Comment: For your 2nd question, you can refer to [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154115/android-volley-self-signed-https-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found/32219177#32219177)