# Using HTTPS to download an image in Android Stidio

Tags: android, https, certificate, httpurlconnection, self-signed

This is what I am doing. I am downloading a JSON file that contains HTTP and HTTPS websites. These websites are images. I want to display these images in my app. For the HTTP it works perfectly, but for the HTTPS it says there is no image to download. So basically it is not reaching to the HTTPS. I am using the Android Dev sites way of accessing the HTTPS connection, but that is where I think my problem is coming from. 
I have the selfsigned cert in a folder res/raw and I access that using the Resources. 
The if statement does break out the two HTTP and HTTPS websites and works fine as far as I can tell. Can i do this like I am doing or is there a better way of doing this?
Thank you for any help.

```
public class ImageDownloaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
Resources resources = null;


public ImageDownloaderTask(ImageView imageView) {
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params)
{
    return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        bitmap = null;
    }

    if (imageViewReference != null) {
        ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            if (bitmap != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            } else {
                Log.d("Downloading the image: ", "No Image found");
            }
        }

    }
}

//URL connection to download the image
private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {

    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection2 = null;
    try {

        //check to see if the image is coming from a HTTP connection
        //then download via a HTTP connection
        //if not then use a HTTPS connection
        if(url.contains("https"))
        {
            try {
                Log.d("Use HTTPS", url);
                URL urlHTTPS = new URL(url);
                urlConnection2 = (HttpsURLConnection) urlHTTPS.openConnection();

                // Load CAs from an InputStream
                // (could be from a resource or ByteArrayInputStream or ...)
                CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
                InputStream caInput = resources.getAssets().open("fusionsystemca.crt");
                Log.d("CA: ", caInput.toString());
                //InputStream caInput = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(resources.getAssets().open("myca.crt")));
                Certificate ca;
                try {
                    ca = cf.generateCertificate(caInput);
                    System.out.println("ca=" + ((X509Certificate) ca).getSubjectDN());
                } finally {
                    caInput.close();
                }

                // Create a KeyStore containing our trusted CAs
                String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
                KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
                keyStore.load(null, null);
                keyStore.setCertificateEntry("ca", ca);

                // Create a TrustManager that trusts the CAs in our KeyStore
                String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
                TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
                tmf.init(keyStore);

                // Create an SSLContext that uses our TrustManager
                SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
                context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
                urlConnection2.setSSLSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());

                int statusCode = urlConnection2.getResponseCode();
                Log.d("URL2 Status: " , Integer.toString(statusCode));
                //check if the HTTP status code is equal to 200, which means that it is ok
                if (statusCode != 200) {
                    return null;
                }
                InputStream in = urlConnection2.getInputStream();
                if (in != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
                    return bitmap;
                }
            }catch (Exception e)
            {
                urlConnection2.disconnect();
                Log.d("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
            }

        }else
        {
            URL uri = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            //check if the HTTP status code is equal to 200, which means that it is ok
            if (statusCode != 200) {
                return null;
            }

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
        Log.d("ImageDownloader", "Error downloading image from " + url);
    } finally {
        if (urlConnection != null) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        if(urlConnection2 != null)
        {
            urlConnection2.disconnect();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

//this is to add the selfsigned cert
```

}

Edits:
I am still stuck with this error
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
which is the cert is not being accepted.
I went so far to add this method to the code so that every cert will be allowed and it still gives me the same issues.

```
public  void trustAllHosts() {

    X509TrustManager easyTrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {

        public void checkClientTrusted(
                X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {

        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(
                X509Certificate[] chain,
                String authType) throws CertificateException {

        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            return null;
        }

    };

    // Create a trust manager that does not validate certificate chains
    TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {easyTrustManager};

    // Install the all-trusting trust manager
    try {
        SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");

        sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32154115/android-volley-self-signed-https-trust-anchor-for-certification-path-not-found/32219177#32219177 to see if it can help or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure the ssl certificates that you are trying to access are enlisted as "trusted" ? I had a similar problem where i was trying to access a resource with comodo certificate which was not trusted so it kept on breaking..

Comment: No its self-signed. I thought that is what the certificate factory code would handle.

Comment: get info on what certificates you are dealing with, sometimes factory might not allow certain certificates, try accessing the website through your mobile browser, that might give you an idea why you are not able to access...

Comment: I tried to access it via my phone and it gave me this Your connection is not private
its security cert is not trusted by my devices os.. But, if I accept the risk it will open up the image fine.