# Unable to connect websocket with wss in android

Tags: java, android, websocket, android-webservice

I am trying to connect with secure websocket connection wss:// in android using org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient API, but unable to connect with https. However it is working fine with ws://.. Here is my code.

```
private void connect(String websocketEndPointUrl) throws Exception {
    URI uri;
    try {

        websocketEndPointUrl="wss://echo.websocket.org:443";
        Log.i(TAG, " WSURL: " + websocketEndPointUrl);

        uri = new URI(websocketEndPointUrl);
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        return;
    }

    mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri,new Draft_17()) {
        @Override
        public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
         }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(String s) {
            //final String message =s;

         }

        @Override
        public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
         }

        @Override
        public void onError(Exception e) {
            Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
         }
    };
    mWebSocketClient.connect();
}
```

i am using online test websocket url: 
ws://echo.websocket.org (port 80) // working with that
wss://echo.websocket.org (port 443)
As per my observation there is no need of certificate required in my code. Can anyone suggest me what is a reason and how i can fix this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Find a solution. I don't know why this is not a part of the documentation. You just need to set **setWebSocketFactory** after WebSocketClient initialization and before the `.connect()` method

```
mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri,new Draft_17()) 
{
    @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
        Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String s) {
        //final String message =s;

    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
        Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
};

if (websocketEndPointUrl.indexOf("wss") == 0) 
{
    try {
        SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getDefault();
        mWebSocketClient.setWebSocketFactory(new DefaultSSLWebSocketClientFactory(sslContext));
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

mWebSocketClient.connect();
```

Comment: This is crazy. I've searched the whole internet to find this trick. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Azade what is the package for WebSocketClient ?

Comment: @WISHY import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
Gradle Dependency: implementation "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0"

Other packages required for the above code(Just for the information):
import org.java_websocket.client.DefaultSSLWebSocketClientFactory;
import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;
import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I need two thing to fix *"Trust anchor for certification path not found*" error when websocket `connect()`:

1. `HttpsURLConnection` requests that particular wss host (but in `https://` form) successfully at least once.
2. Then do`setWebSocketFactory()` as mentioned in accepted answer. Which this extra method (plus `new Draft_17()`) only appeared in library version `org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0`, not `1.4.0`.

Note that don't test with `allowAllSSL()` like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27603256/1074998) do, which affect the two thing above not working.