# Socket connecting : ECONNREFUSED

Tags: android, sockets

I am used the below code to connect to a php websocket.

```
serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip_str);
                socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port_str);
                mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
```

Trying to open a socket and want to listen to what data is coming from the server.

the ip_str is something like this : wss://xyz.com:8181/game where xyz is the actual host name, and 8181 is a dummy port number(have given dummy values as i cannot give the actual values here - but it is working fine on web as we are trying to connect same socket via web).

On this line :

```
socket = new Socket(serverAddr, port_str);
```

I am getting the following error message :

```
java.net.ConnectException: failed to connect to ip6-localhost/::1 (port 8181): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

Anyone has any idea why i am facing this issue?

Comment: Nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to.

Comment: Did not understand, as i am new to sockets. It is working fine in web.

Comment: It looks like `port` was zero. That cannot possibly be correct.

Comment: But i have given the port as 8181(dummy value)

Comment: But the error message clearly says `(port 0)`.

Comment: error because no one is listening on that ip/port. Use telnet command to confirm

telnet <ip_str> <port_str>

@EJP has correctly pointed out

Comment: But as i have shown in the code above, i have given the port, that is what i am noit understanding, that why is it showing port 0 if i have given the port value?

Comment: You haven't shown anything except the *name* of a variable incorrectly called `port_str`. It isn't a string, and you haven't *shown* that its value is 8181, or indeed anything non-zero. The error message doesn't agree with you.

Comment: sorry, i got the issue of port 0, now i am getting error as port 8181(editted the question)

Comment: So nothing was listening at port 8181 either.

Comment: so how do i solve the problem? as it is listeing on web. is there any different method to connect a wss socket?

Comment: are you running the app on emulator or real device ?

Comment: real device, with internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ip_str` is a full URL like `"wss://xyz.com:8181/game"` then the following line is completely wrong:

```
serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(ip_str);
```

You can't pass a URL to `InetAddress.getByName()`.  It only accepts a dotted IP address or a hostname as input, eg:

```
serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("xyz.com");
```

So, use the [`URI`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URI.html) or [`URL`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URL.html) class to parse the URL into its constituent components, and then you can resolve the hostname component to an IP address, eg:

```
URI WebSocketUri = new URI("wss://xyz.com:8181/game"); // or URL
serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(WebSocketUri.getHost());
...
```

Or, you can let `Socket` resolve the host for you:

```
URI WebSocketUri = new URI("wss://xyz.com:8181/game"); // or URL
if (WebSocket.getScheme() == "wss")
    socket = new SSLSocket(WebSocket.getHost(), WebSocket.getPort());
else
    socket = new Socket(WebSocket.getHost(), WebSocket.getPort());
// send an HTTP request for WebSocket.getRawPath() and negotiate WebSocket handshake as needed...
```

Or better, use [`URLConnection`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/URLConnection.html) instead:

```
WebSocketUri = new URL("wss://xyz.com:8181/game");
URLConnection conn = WebSocketUri.openConnection();
...
```

Or, use an actual 3rd party WebSocket library (of which there are many available for Android).

Comment: this is now working fine, thank you. but then i am facing an issue that the server does not get my request. it shows an error on server

Comment: @ParthAnjaria that is a different issue than the one you asked here. Please post a new question, and be sure to show your latest code.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are trying to connect via secured/encrypted connection, `wss://`. You need extra step before your app can connect to the target address. It is usually by setting the certificate first.

You may check this solution:
[Unable to connect websocket with wss in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36150164/unable-to-connect-websocket-with-wss-in-android). More information here:
[how to create Socket connection in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384678/how-to-create-socket-connection-in-android)

Comment: The connection (the TCP connection) would still succeed in that case, it would need additional steps to achieve a full-fledged websocket connection. In other words, the error message would not be ECONNREFUSED