# No Connection error in Volley and Socket Time out in HttpClient by Async Task

Tags: android, sockets, asynchronous, android-volley

I have spend near about 3 days in this issue of **No Time error of Volley**,

I am calling 10 web APIs sequentially, at 4th web API I am getting No Connection error of volley, out of 12 there are specifically 4 web APIs which are giving me same error(tries asynchronous as well).

I tried same by Async Task using Http Client getting Socket Time out error for the same web APis.
Note : All these web APIs are working in IOS as well as postman properly.

Can any one please let me know that this is the android side issue or from server side, if its of android please tell me the solution , how can I get rid of it?

Comment: you need to show your code and logcat output. Also please format you question into simple paragraphs and line breaks rather than only one.

Comment: I hope you are using a queue for those requests, if you are starting 12 requests at the same time, yeah most of them will fail because the mobile platform supports max 4 connections at the same time. It would also help to add the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue after doing lots of work around.

> Issue was of SSL Certification, As volley doesn't support SSL so need to allow externally.

To allow SSL Refer : [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17045795/making-a-https-request-using-android-volley)   Create a HttpsTrustManager class that implements X509TrustManager: